# ¿por que nada mas retorna un solo valor el JSON encode de la consulta, cuando con el var_dump me retorna 179 filas?

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, json

Buen día compañeros. eh estado intentando realizar una tabla que muestre datos y que esta realice busquedas en tiempo real. el caso es que la consulta que realizo nada mas me retorna como tal un solo registro, cuando debería de mostrarme más.

aqui es donde hago la consulta a la bd.

```
<?php 

require('../modelo/config.php'); 

$consulta = "SELECT CE.ID_USUARIO, PL.NOMBRES, PL.CORREO_E,UROL.ID_ROL , CAL.ID_ALCANCE,
CROL.DESCRIPCION as [descripcion del rol], CAL.DESCRIPCION as [descripcion del alcance]
from CE_CAT_USUARIO as CE, PL_PERSONAL as PL, 
CE_CAT_ROL as CROL, CE_USUARIO_ROL as UROL, CE_CAT_ALCANCE as CAL
where CE.ID_PERSONA = PL.ID_PERSONA 
AND
CE.ID_USUARIO = UROL.ID_USUARIO
and
UROL.ID_ROL = CROL.ID_ROL
and
UROL.ID_ALCANCE = CAL.ID_ALCANCE
order by CE.ID_USUARIO";

$val = sqlsrv_query($conn,$consulta); 

if (sqlsrv_has_rows($val)) {
    while($resultado = sqlsrv_fetch_array($val)){
        $html = ''; 
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["ID_USUARIO"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["NOMBRES"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["CORREO_E"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["ID_ROL"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["ID_ALCANCE"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["descripcion del rol"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["descripcion del alcance"].'</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';   
    }
}else{
    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td colspan="7">sin resultados</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';
}

echo json_encode($html,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 

?>
```

estos datos los quiero mostrar aquí.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero esa es la única fila que me retorna.

esos datos los pongo aqui.

```
 <table class="table table-striped"> 
                    <thead>
                        <th>Id usuario</th>
                        <th>Nombres</th>
                        <th>Correo</th>
                        <th>Rol</th>
                        <th>Alcance</th>
                        <th>Desc Rol</th>
                        <th>Desc alcance</th>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody id="content">
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tbody>
               </table>
```

siento que no hay problemas con el table. pero puede que se me haya pasado algo y no me haya dado cuenta. los datos los pongo en esa tabla después con un script.

```
<script>
       getdata(); 

        function getdata(){
            //peticiion 
            var input = document.getElementById("campo").value
            var content = document.getElementById("content")
            var url = "../controlador/load.php"
            var formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('campo',input)

            fetch(url,{
                method: "POST", 
                body: formData
            }).then(Response => Response.json())
            .then(data =>{
                content.innerHTML = data
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
    </script>
```

ustedes que tienen más experiencia. ¿será que me puedan ayudar?

Comment: Pero porque estás haciendo `json_encode` a un html?

Comment: Cuál es el problema específico? En qué necesitas que te ayudemos? Qué debería pasar y no pasa?

Comment: @Pipe lo que pasa es que guardo en una variable $html los resultados para posteriormente mostrarlos, en el script... pido ese JSON para mostrar los datos en el table

Comment: @Alfabravo deberia mostrarme mas registros. pero solo me muestra 1

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que en cada ciclo del while, estás asignando tu variable `$html` a vacío, es por eso que sólo te devuelve el último valor que tiene tu variable `$html`:

```
while($resultado = sqlsrv_fetch_array($val)){
  $html = '';
  // ...
}
```

La solución sería mover esta variable fuera del while, para que así no se vuelva a asignar a vacío su valor en cada ciclo:

```
$html = '';
while($resultado = sqlsrv_fetch_array($val)){
  // ...
}
```

Comment: lo intente así ... pero ahora no me devuelve ningún valor :C, la variable como tal si tiene los datos pero no los muestra, si la puse afuera del if.
la puse abajo del require pero no me muestra nada . jejej :c

Comment: y si, como dices ... si la dejaba dentro del while solo agarraba el ultimo valor ... ya la puse afuera. pero no se por que ahora no me pone nada en la tabla

Comment: Que extraño.. si pruebas con `echo $html`? porque usas el `json_encode`?

Comment: o que tu `tbody` que quede así `<tbody id="content"></tbody>`

Comment: bueno lo uso por que en la funcion de JS lo mando a llamar el JSON

Answer (score 0):

1. La variable `$html` debe ser declarada e inicializada vacía fuera del `if` para poder que sea accesible en cualquier lugar. Si la pones dentro del ciclo `while`, solo te va a retornar el último registro y si la pones dentro de la instrucción `if` no estaría declarada en caso de que entre al `else`.
2. Quita el `json_encode` y retorna el `html` tal cual fue construido.

```
$val = sqlsrv_query($conn,$consulta); 
$html = '';

if (sqlsrv_has_rows($val)) {
    while($resultado = sqlsrv_fetch_array($val)){
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["ID_USUARIO"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["NOMBRES"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["CORREO_E"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["ID_ROL"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["ID_ALCANCE"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["descripcion del rol"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$resultado["descripcion del alcance"].'</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';   
    }
}else{
    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td colspan="7">sin resultados</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';
}
echo $html;
```

3. En `fetch`, recibes el `html` y lo pasas directamente a la tabla.

```
fetch(url,{
  method: "POST", 
  body: formData
}).then(Response => content.innerHTML = Response)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Si aún no funciona, pasa `Response` por consola para ver que datos te trae.

Comment: lo intentaré... muchas gracias :)

Comment: ya lo pude probar ... pero lo unico que me pone es [OBJECT RESPONSE] y no muestra nada

Comment: Bien, en ese caso sería necesario depurar paso a paso para determinar en qué punto se está quedando atascado el proceso. Prueba con `.then(Response => console.log(Response))`. Si logramos coincidir, iniciamos un chat acá mismo para abordar el tema. Espero tus comentarios.

Comment: lo intentare ...

Answer (score 0):

Como estas, solo debes cambiar la forma en que armas y devuelves los datos...

Primeramente estas borrando tu mismo los resultados, saca el inicio de la variable $html del while debe ser asi

```
$html = '';
while($resultado = sqlsrv_fetch_array($val)){
```

En php retorna

```
echo $html;
```

y en el fetch de javascript, le comentas que vas a recibir formato plano

```
.then(Response => Response.text())
```

Deberia funcionar

Comment: lo intentaré :)